# Exact text match if statement python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, string-matching

I'm trying to find an 'exact text match' using the below code. The website is: https://www.girafferestaurant.co.nz/menu. When I print (soup.find_all(text=True)) I can get the text back and search, but I just want to match or no match depending if the word/phrase (in this case 'offering at Giraffe') is in the statement.

Below is what I've tried.

```
text = soup.find_all(text=True)
if 'offering at Giraffe' in text:
     print ("Match")
else: 
     print ("No Match")
```

Also, I've used text = soup.find_all('p') but the text is not always in p tags, as it's across different sites.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Did you try debugging this yourself?  For instance, `print` the value of `text`; does it, indeed contain a string element with the value you want?

Comment: Is `'offering at Giraffe'` embedded within the output, rather than a stand-alone string?  If so, you need the `index` method -- read the documentation of that and the `in` operator to make sure you're using the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import bs4
import requests

url = 'https://www.girafferestaurant.co.nz/menu'
r  = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

text = soup.find_all(text=True)
matches = []

for item in text:
    if 'offering at Giraffe' in item:
        matches.append(item)

if matches != []:
    print ('Match')
else: 
     print ("No Match")
```

EDIT: for your follow up. If you just want to check through out the entire text:

```
import bs4
import requests

url = 'https://www.girafferestaurant.co.nz/menu'
r  = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

text = soup.text
matches = []

if 'offering at Giraffe' in text and 'customised set' not in text:
        matches.append(text)

if matches != []:
    print ('Match')
else: 
     print ("No Match")
```

Comment: using the same statement do you know how I would also exclude text? Want to exclude the word 'menu? : So I'm looking for 'offering at Giraffe' within text, but want to exclude the word 'customised set', in this case it would return "No Match" as the words customised set' is in the text. I've tried this but it does work if 'offering at Giraffe' in item, not in 'customised set' in item:

Comment: it's checking each item in the list. it still matches, because that particular item doesn't include 'customised set'. Unless, you want it to check the text as a whole text, not checking each line by line individually

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to search by text with `BeautifulSoup`:

- [searching function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function). Use a function as the `text` value:

  ```
  results = soup.find_all(text=lambda text: text and 'offering at Giraffe' in text)
  ```
- [regular expression](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression). Use a regular expression pattern as the `text` value:

  ```
  import re

  results = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'offering at Giraffe'))
  ```